# IllegalArgumentException When Trying to Write to Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase and creating my sign up flow.

For regular email/password authentication, I am able to successfully write to Cloud Firestore. I have viewed my data in the actual Database, so I know it is being written successfully:

```
           @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            Log.v("INPUT_TEXT", user.getDisplayName());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user.getDisplayName().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Map<String, Object> userMap = new HashMap<>();
            userMap.put("Display_Name", user.getDisplayName());
            userMap.put("ID", user.getUid());
            userMap.put("Provider", user.getProviders());
            mStoreBaseRef.collection("Users").add(userMap);
        }
    });
```

However, with Facebook authentication:

```
private void handleFacebookAccessToken(AccessToken token) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

    AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                    FirebaseAuth loggedInAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    String ID = loggedInAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    String displayName = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
                    HashMap<String, Object> id = new HashMap<>();
                    id.put("user_id", ID);
                    id.put("display_name", displayName);
                    id.put("provider", mAuth.getCurrentUser().getProviderData());
                    mStoreBaseRef.collection("Users").add(id);

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication_Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdnb
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzl.zzqe(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzk.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzk.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzk.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzk.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.firestore.zzk.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.set(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference.add(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at com.troychuinard.fanpolls.SignupActivity$2.onComplete(SignupActivity.java:180)
                                                                           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5527)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

Comment: What are you expecting to be stored in the user's "provider" property?  Look carefully at what `mAuth.getCurrentUser().getProviderData()` returns.  Also, why are you storing user data regardless of success or failure.  Seems like you'd only want to write if the task is successful.

Comment: I am simply trying to tracker their sign-up method (i.e. email, Facebook)

Comment: `getProviderData()` returns a list of `UserInfo` objects.  You should iterate that and look inside the `UserInfo` objects for the strings you want to store in the database.  Don't just try to stick that whole list into the database.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens when we can't automatically convert the type you've given us to one we support (similar to [custom objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects)). Check the types you're putting into `userMap` and, if necessary, opt for simpler ones. (See the doc for more info.)